# RedHat Satellite/Katello and Hiera

Tags: redhat, hiera, satellite, katello

I'm using RedHat Satellite 6.1.1, and am successfully syncing Puppet modules from a local forge into the Katello part of Satellite.

However, I'm not sure how to go about syncing my Hiera data.

Obviously I'd like to leverage the lifecycle management features of Katello to control the data, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Do I add the Puppet git repository as a source? Surely that would mess up the available puppet modules?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we set up a simple bash script that uses `rsync` to copy the hiera data from Git to Satellite and all Capsules. We use Git to provide version control so that we can revert data if needed.

By not using Katello we gain the added advantage of being able to change parameters without having to do another Publish/Promote dance in Satellite (which can take much time).